# Recreate left-to-right scrolling text in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a fast typing effect through packing a label in tkinter. When I run this code, it prints left to right as I want it to, but the letters are spaced far apart and the spaces print {} brackets instead.

How can I remove the brackets and just show a space? Is there also a cleaner and easier way to do the scrolling effect other than the list method I used?

```
root = Tk()
delay = 50
label_var = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable=label_var, height=10)
num = 0

def scroll():
    global num
    roll_text = list(message) # Edit: deleted this line
    num = num + 1
    label_var.set(roll_text[1:num]) # Edit: changed roll_text to message
    root.after(delay, scroll)

message = ' This message should be scrolling left to right. '
scroll()
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: change `roll_text = list(message)` to `roll_text = message`

Answer (score 0):

The brackets are appearing because you're converting the string to a list. When tkinter is given a list where it expects a string it uses Tcl's rules for converting the list back to a string. Those rules include using curly braces to preserve the original data.

The solution is simple: don't pass a list to `label_var.set`.

As for the alignment, because you don't provide any alignment options, tkinter will try to center the widget. A simple solution for this specific case is to pass `side='left'` to the `pack` command.